# Scipy optimization curve fit not working properly

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data to 4 parameter logistics, and I got a graph like this:

[image: figure1]

I think the curve for the 4th~10th data points looks fine but I don't understand what is happening for the 1st~3rd data points. I also got the error message

> "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power return ((A-D)/(1.0+((x/C)**B))) + D".

The codes used to make the graph are as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import scipy.optimize as optimization

xdata = np.array([0.00001, 0.000033, 0.0001, 0.00033, 
                  0.001, 0.0033, 0.01, 0.033, 0.1, 0.33])
ydata = np.array([591, 648.5, 714.75, 941, 1226, 1768.25, 
                  2232.25, 2716.25, 3056.25, 3034.5])
ydata2 = np.array([595.5, 711, 898.25, 2215.5, 
                  2791.25, 3115.5, 3351, 3301, 3456.25, 3171.5])
ydata3 = np.array([617, 597.5, 599.25, 680, 683.5, 1152.75, 1554.25, 
                  2221.5, 2821.5, 2719.25])

def fourPL(x, A, B, C, D):
    return ((A-D)/(1.0+((x/C)**B))) + D

params, params_covariance = optimization.curve_fit(fourPL, xdata,     
        ydata)

x_min, x_max = np.amin(xdata), np.amax(xdata)
xs = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 1000)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xs, fourPL(xs, *params))
plt.semilogx()
plt.show()
```

**For your information**

- when I used only 7 data points, then curve fit well.
- when I used `xdata` in log form from the first and added 6 to make the numbers positive `(xdata_log = np.log10(xdata)+6)`, it worked perfect with 10 data points.

I don't understand what is happening.
Any advices or comments would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we plot the curve along with its data points it becomes clear what's happening:

```
plt.plot(xs, fourPL(xs, *params), '.-')
```

[image]

There are only two points in the left part, which are linearly interpolated. That is an issue with plotting linearly spaced data on a logarithmic axis.

Use [`np.logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) instead of `np.linspace` for regular spacing on the logarithmic axis:

```
x_min, x_max = np.amin(xdata), np.amax(xdata)
xs = np.logspace(np.log10(x_min), np.log10(x_max), 1000)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xs, fourPL(xs, *params))
plt.semilogx()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I didn't think that way. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MrT I didn't fully understand the system. Thanks for letting me know.